# selenium .send_keys() doesn't work for element.text

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I need to enter text that appeared before on the screen, specifically a number, this is the code I am using:

```
while True:
    try:
        number = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div > div.big-number")
        break
    except:
        pass

print(number.text)

while True:
    try:
        text_field = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.css-1qvtbrk:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(1)")
        print("Found text field")
        break
    except:
        pass

numberstr = number.text
text_field.send_keys(numberstr) # doesn´t work
```

I have tried:

```
text_field.send_keys(str(number.text)) # doesn't work
text_field.send_keys("1") # works but I need it to be a variable
text_field.send_keys(number.text + " ") # doesn't work
```

the print(number.text) does print the number correctly

Comment: tested placing the `text_field.send_keys()` inside the while loop and after the print, it does print meaning it finds the field but doesn't type instead it refinds the element. Also, the error says the element is stale. and still doesn't work if I try
`driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.css-1qvtbrk:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(1)").send_keys(numbers.text)`

Comment: `text_field.send_keys(numberstr) # doesn´t work` What exactly do you mean "doesn't work"?  What happens when you try?  If you get an error, or unwanted results, **explain**.

Comment: It doesn't type anything, and I get this error:
`selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element with the reference a92bafc9-4318-4295-a16e-9a497d9cbb02 is stale; either its node document is not the active document, or it is no longer connected to the DOM;`

Comment: can you post the URL?

Comment: Of Course, https://humanbenchmark.com/tests/number-memory

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, the number element no longer existed when I called `number.text` so I just needed to set the value before that happens

```
while True:
    try:
        number = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div > div.big-number")
        break
    except:
        pass

number_str = number.text

while True:
    try:
        text_field = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.css-1qvtbrk:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(1)")
        print("Found text field")
        break
    except:
        pass

text_field.send_keys(number_str)
```